# What is the path of photos album on iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, path, device, photos, writetofile

I was trying to save a PNG file to photos albums folder on the iPhone device with a .png extension so that the transparency remains..

My question is:
What is the path of photos album UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function is using?
I am using data write to file method..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access assets on the file system directly (assuming this isn't a jailbreak question). In addition to UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, the [Assets Library Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) provides access to the photo library if you're targeting newer versions of iOS.

Comment: would using that framework help me save a file in png format to the albums folder in the photo library?

Comment: @tiw: check out UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum — http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Comment: I think so. I don't believe there's a "copy file to asset" function but if you read the png into an NSData you can then use `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock`.

Answer (score 1):

Root/private/var/mobile/Media/DCMI/100APPLE

Comment: What is "Root"?

Comment: Yes, an old reply :) It was a jailbroken iPhone 3GS it seems