# How to get path of an image from iOS photo library in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a use-case where I just need the path to an image (whose name is known) stored in the photos library of iPhone. Internet search suggested `UIImagePickerController`, but I do not need to pick and display the image.

[What is the path of photos album on iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945368/what-is-the-path-of-photos-album-on-iphone-device])

Above question also does not contain any clue.

Comment: The path is meaningless, due to the sandboxing of iOS. The user has to pick the image in order for its data to be provided to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23781343/9673374 This might be helpful

Comment: @ketakiDamale I seriously doubt it actually might. DocumentsDirectory is relative to the path of the app, while Sankalp is trying to access the photo album

Comment: "I have a use-case where I just need the path to an image (whose name is known) stored in the photos library of iPhone" No, you don't. There are no images in the photos library, there are assets; the assets don't have names; and there are no paths (except for asset URLs). That is exactly what the linked question/answer tells you.